# Ignore outside variables in exec

Tags: python

I wish to use exec command in Python such that no outside variables will be considered in it.
For example:

```
x=2
exec('print(x)')
```

Now I want this code to fetch an error saying that x is not defined since x was not there in the exec command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `exec` an empty `globals` dictionary:

```
>>> x=2
>>> exec("print(x)")
2
>>> exec("print(x)", {})
```

---

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

---

The documentation of `exec`:

> ```
> exec(source, globals=None, locals=None, /)
>     Execute the given source in the context of globals and locals.
>     
>     The source may be a string representing one or more Python statements
>     or a code object as returned by compile().
>     The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
>     defaulting to the current globals and locals.
>     If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
> ```